# Android Widget: Service vs Async Task

Tags: android, asynchronous, service, widget

When it comes to widgets can we call an async task from within a service?

I currently have a tiny app that looks up live sports scores and displays the same. The main class calls an async task. The async task calls 2 procedures. The first one to parse an XML file and get an html link. The second one to read through that html file.
Now I want to convert this app into a home screen widget.

Can I call my async task from within the service ?
Any pointers to examples?

Please help.

Regards,
Sam

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to create the AsyncTask in the Service. The Service is already running on a background thread so you can do whatever intensive tasks you were doing in doInBackground in the Service. You should still be able to call the AsyncTask in the Service but you don't need to use an AsyncTask at that point.

[Here](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/04/introducing-home-screen-widgets-and.html) is a widget example with a Service.

Answer (score 0):

If the original activity and the service are in the same package, or one is appropriately dependent on the other, then you can call the same async task with no problem. As long as the async task is in a generic format, so it provides the data back to whatever calls it (via a callback or handler), instead of always posting the results to the UI of the application, there will be no major issues.

Comment: hmm how could I use a handler or callback. I think this might be what i am missing in my problem here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20792944/appwidgetprovider-public-void-onenabled-context-context-does-not-effect-widget

Answer (score 0):

Here is the basic differences:

Threads or Async task perform their tasks in a background thread thus they do not block the main thread, while a service performs it’s work in the main thread. so if a service is performing an intensive task such as calling a web service, it may block the main thread until it finishes. So for intensive tasks a service should run it’s work in a background thread.

Summary, Thread (Async Task) perform task in background (not block main thread) and Service can block main thread until it finishes.