# AppWidgetProvider public void onEnabled (Context context) does not effect widget

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-widget, textview

I am using an AppWidgetProvider and attempting to override the onEnabled which I assume is what is called when the app gets added to the home screen from the user. My AppWidgetProvider class looks like this and calls an async task which is supposed to update my text view:

```
package com.example.beerportfoliopro;

import android.appwidget.AppWidgetManager;
import android.appwidget.AppWidgetProvider;
import android.content.Context;

/**
 * Created by Mike on 12/26/13.
 */
public class HelloWidget extends AppWidgetProvider {

    @Override
    public void onEnabled(Context context){

        //build url for async task
        String url = "hiddenURL";

        //call async task
        new GetRandomBeer(context).execute(url);



    }

    @Override
    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds){

        //todo: call update code, which should be the same as onEnabled


    }


}
```

My widget xml file that displays what the widget looks like is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="@drawable/widget_bg_normal"
    >


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/widget_tv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="testing 123"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
        android:padding="10dip"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        >
    </TextView>

</LinearLayout>
```

And my async task which will eventually parse some JSON to add to my widget looks like this:

```
public class GetRandomBeer extends AsyncTask
        <String, Void, String> {

    Context c;

    public GetRandomBeer(Context context)
    {
        c = context;

    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return readJSONFeed(arg0[0]);
    }



    protected void onPostExecute(String result){
        Log.d("taste","Inside get taste");
        //decode json here
        try{

            //todo: get all beer data



            //todo: set text views with data
            TextView breweryTitle = (TextView) ((Activity) c).findViewById(R.id.widget_tv);
            breweryTitle.setText("changed in the async task!");




        }
        catch(Exception e){

        }


    }

    public String readJSONFeed(String URL) {
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(URL);
        try {
            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
            StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
            int statusCode = statusLine.getStatusCode();
            if (statusCode == 200) {
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                InputStream inputStream = entity.getContent();
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
                String line;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    stringBuilder.append(line);
                }
                inputStream.close();
            } else {
                Log.d("JSON", "Failed to download file");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("readJSONFeed", e.getLocalizedMessage());
        }
        return stringBuilder.toString();
    }

}
```

Based on my code above, when the user adds the widget to their homes screen it should run onEnabled() which should call my async task and change the textview from saying "testing 123" to "change in the async task!"

Right now nothing is changing and I can not figure out why.

**Update:**

Here is code I have in my manifest related to my widget:

```
   <receiver android:name="com.example.beerportfoliopro.HelloWidget" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter> <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
            <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_ENABLED" />
        </intent-filter>
```

I also know my async task is getting called because I just put some Log.d into it and it is running the async task its just not setting the textview value in the widget.

**Update 2**

I have also tried to use remote view with the suggested answer below and now I have this in my async task:

```
 @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        String beerText =  "try number 3";

        AppWidgetManager mgr = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(c);
        int[] appWidgetIds = mgr.getAppWidgetIds(new ComponentName(c, HelloWidget.class));

        //You need a static method somewhere (I usually put in widget provider class)
        //that builds the RemoteView and sets everything up.
        RemoteViews rv = HelloWidget.buildRemoteViews(c, mgr, appWidgetIds);

        rv.setTextViewText(R.id.widget_tv, beerText);

        mgr.updateAppWidget(appWidgetIds, rv);


        return readJSONFeed(arg0[0]);
    }
```

But I get a cannot resolve method error

```
 RemoteViews rv = HelloWidget.buildRemoteViews(c, mgr, appWidgetIds);
```

under `buildRemoteViews`

Comment: do I need something about remote views for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Register for the broadcast in your manifest:

```
<receiver android:name="MyWidget" android:label="Widget">
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
    <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_ENABLED" />
</intent-filter>
....
</receiver>
```

Also note this about onEnabled():

"This is called when an instance the App Widget is created for the first time. For example, if the user adds two instances of your App Widget, this is only called the first time."

You also have the fact that onUpdate() will be called anyway when an instance is added, so doing the same thing in onEnabled() may be redundant.

Also, once you get that AsyncTask to execute, you're going to have a host of problems, first of which is the Context object is not an Activity.

EDIT: Now that your method is being called, you will need to set the text using RemoteViews. You don't need to do it in onPostExecute() since this is cross-process update.

```
protected Void doInBackground(String... arg0) {

    String beerText =  readJSONFeed(arg0[0]);

    AppWidgetManager mgr = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(c);
    int[] appWidgetIds = mgr.getAppWidgetIds(new ComponentName(c, HelloWidget.class));

    //You need a static method somewhere (I usually put in widget provider class) 
    //that builds the RemoteView and sets everything up.
    RemoteViews rv = HelloWidget.buildRemoteViews(c, mgr, appWidgetIds);

    rv.setTextViewText(R.id.text_view_in_layout, beerText);

    mgr.updateAppWidget(appWidgetIds, rv);
}
```

That will update all your AppWidget's, if you only want one to update, you will need to pass in it's id.

Comment: I just updated my post with code I have in my manifest already. Going to add the ENABLED one and see what happens. What problems do you see me having here?

Comment: SO this still didnt change the text after I added that line. Also the reason why the onUpdate() is going to be the same is because the api returns a random beer each time it is called.

Comment: Just did some more tinkering and I am getting into my async task. Its just not able to set the text view value for some reason. @svenoaks

Comment: I was just about to add about that, one sec.

Comment: ok I get a cannot resolve method on RemoteViews rv = HelloWidget.buildRemoteViews(c, mgr, appWidgetIds); under buildRemoteViews

Answer (score 0):

The buildRemoteViews() method isn't how you get a RemoteViews object in a widget; use a constructor instead.

```
RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.appwidget_provider_layout);
```

No offense, but this is pretty clearly laid in the example in the [API guide for App Widgets](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html#AppWidgetProvider).

Comment: I stated in my comment that he needed to create this method (he might need more than a simple layout inflated), which would include that line. Yes he does need to read the documentation.